# Vagrant bridged network using virtual interfaces

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, vagrant

On my Root Server I use Vagrant (v1) for virtualization. To give some machines their own IP adress, I tried to use this: `config.vm.network :bridged`

But it doesn't worked for me. My Server has 5 IP adresses, 4 of them are virtual interfaces. They look like this: eth0:1, eth0:2, etc.

Is there a way to use this interfaces in Vagrant?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is VirtualBox (v4.2.16) does not support virtual interfaces. You cannot select them in network adapters.

This is cannot be a problem with vagrant, but with VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks man! Would it help to use later version of VirtualBox?

Comment: Morphesus, My VirtualBox was current as of that moment. Have to wait until they implement this... :(